# Download data in parallel

Tags: parallelism

I have to download 20G of data using ftp .Can I do this in parallel(gnu?)
Here are some of the links for the data.

```
 ftp://ftp.sra.ebi.ac.uk/vol1/fastq/ERR030/ERR030893/ERR030893.fastq.gz 
 ftp://ftp.sra.ebi.ac.uk/vol1/fastq/ERR030/ERR030885/ERR030885_1.fastq.gz
 ftp://ftp.sra.ebi.ac.uk/vol1/fastq/ERR030/ERR030885/ERR030885_2.fastq.gz
 ftp://ftp.sra.ebi.ac.uk/vol1/fastq/ERR030/ERR030894/ERR030894.fastq.gz
 ftp://ftp.sra.ebi.ac.uk/vol1/fastq/ERR030/ERR030886/ERR030886_1.fastq.gz
 ftp://ftp.sra.ebi.ac.uk/vol1/fastq/ERR030/ERR030886/ERR030886_2.fastq.gz
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I don't know about `parallel`, I do know that an excellent tool for downloading in parallel is `aria2c`.

Here's an excerpt from the FTP/HTTP section of [its manual](http://aria2.sourceforge.net/manual/en/html/aria2c.html#options):

- `-s`, `--split=[N]`
- Download a file using `N` connections. If more than `N` URIs are given, first `N` URIs are used and remaining URIs are used for backup. If less than `N` URIs are given, those URIs are used more than once so that `N` connections total are made simultaneously. The number of connections to the same host is restricted by the `--max-connection-per-server` option. See also the `--min-split-size` option
- Default: 5